# How to access package from another service within the same parent

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have created 5 microservices, all having the same parent in pom. I am trying to access a package from one child service `core-service` into another `data-processor`.

Below is my `data-processor` code which is trying to access `com.itqe.tdm.core.model.Customer` from `core-service`

```
package com.itqe.dataprocessor.util;

import org.springframework.batch.item.excel.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.excel.support.rowset.RowSet;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.itqe.tdm.core.model.Customer;

@Component
public class RowMapperImpl implements RowMapper<Customer> {

    @Override
    public Customer mapRow(RowSet rs) throws Exception {
        if (rs == null || rs.getCurrentRow() == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Customer cust = new Customer();
        cust.setFirstName(rs.getColumnValue(0));
        cust.setLastName(rs.getColumnValue(1));

        return cust;
    }



}
```

When I try to build the code `mvn clean install` I am getting the following error

`package com.itqe.tdm.core.model does not exist`

I already did `mvn install` on the parent service as well as `core-service`. The jar is present in my m2. I added the dependency in the pom of `data-processor`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itqe</groupId>
    <artifactId>core-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Could someone please help me understand what am I missing here?
Appreciate the help.

Parent pom.xml

```
<modules>
        <module>config-server</module>
        <module>registry-service</module>
        <module>gateway-service</module>
        <module>core-service</module>
        <module>data-processor</module>
    </modules>
```

Comment: is your code structure having different different module

Comment: yes, I added my parent pom.xml above. please refer. And I am trying to access a package from core-service module into data-processor module.